# How to create a partition in the root in ApacheDS server programmatically using JNDI/LDAP?

Tags: ldap, jndi, apacheds

I'm trying to create a new partition in the root of a ApacheDS Lightweight Directory using JNDI/LDAP. I've failed trying to add it using bind and createSubcontext within the root context. I'm able to create a partition using Apache Directory Studio. Is there a way to programmatically add one using JNDI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a new partition using code, you first need to configure the partition in the
server.xml(if you are using version <= 1.5.7) or in the ou=config area if you are using the latest trunk.
Once you configure the partition and restart the server then using code you can create the
context entry after which the partition is visible for performing other operations.

Comment: I suspected this was the case. When I added a partition to my server.xml and then added the sub-context using JNDI it worked fine.