# Custom partition in ApacheDS

Tags: apacheds

I am using ApacheDS version 2.0.0-M3 (I not very familiar with how this works).  I have created a new partition class, extending AbstractPartition.  I am able to create an instance of this class, and add it to an ApacheDsService instance.

```
    File instancePath = new File( param[0] );
    ApacheDsService service = new ApacheDsService();
    InstanceLayout layout = new InstanceLayout( instancePath );

    try
    {
        service.start(layout);
        //
        TestPartition partition = new TestPartition ( layout );
        partition.setSuffix( "ou=test" );
        partition.setSchemaManager( service.getDirectoryService().getSchemaManager() );
        partition.initialize();
        service.getDirectoryService().addPartition( partition );
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        LOG.error("Failed to start the service.", x);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

However, when I connect to my server with Apache Directory Studio, I cannot see my partition.

I found this question: 
    [How to create a partition in the root in ApacheDS server programmatically using JNDI/LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935612/how-to-create-a-partition-in-the-root-in-apacheds-server-programmatically-using/4946360#4946360)
where kayyagari says that it is necessary to "configure the partition ... in the ou=config area".

I am unsure exactly what is meant by this, and have not had much luck searching the web for details.

I can see the ou=config partition in Apache Directory Studio.  I can see other partitions there: ads-partitionId=system and ads-partitionId=example.  Looking at the objectClass attributes, I can see that these both have one with the value ads-jdbmPartition.  I am unsure whether my partition should have such an entry (as it is not a jdbm partition, but gets its data from a web service).

(Unfortunately, the documentation link for 2.0.0-M3 on the ApacheDS site gives a 404.)  How should the LDIF entry for my custom partition look?  I cannot get it right, and do not know if I am missing something, or if I have entered something incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApacheDS version 2.0.0-M3 (and 2.0.0-M4) appear to be work in progress.  According to the [ApacheDS repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/directory/apacheds/tags/) version 2.0.0-M3 has not seen any activity since August 2011.  In August 2011 the issue with the missing documentation was raised (see: [Broken link in web site ("Basic User's Guide" on ApacheDS 2.0 page)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIR-280)).

From the repository you can also see that version 2.0.0-M4 is being worked on currently (with very recent activity).  There is some 2.0.0-M3 documentation about.  The [2.0.0M3 Maven generated documentation](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/gen-docs/2.0.0-M3/index.html) is available.  It is also possible to download the [2.0.0-M3 source code](http://people.apache.org/~elecharny/apacheds-parent-2.0.0-M3-source-release.zip) which contains numerous unit tests which you could use to decipher the correct approach - the source code is available from [Emmanuel Lécharny personal page](http://people.apache.org/~elecharny/) (but seemingly not on the ApacheDS site itself).  Emmanuel Lécharny appears to be the main committer for version 2.0.0-M3 (and Kiran Ayyagari ([kayyagari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486888/kayyagari)) also appears to be an ApacheDS committer).

Hopefully you now have enough information to allow you to pursue the 2.0.0-M3/M4 route if you so desire.

---

Owing to the lack of documentation for the 2.x branch, I think it would be **MUCH easier** for you to use ApacheDS version 1.5.7 (at least until the 2.x branch is documented).  The 1.5.7 version includes documentation and [working examples](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/4-embedding-apacheds.html) such as embedding ApacheDS into an application and into a web application.

I have tried the [embedded server sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/documentation/samples/trunk/embedded-sample/) and was able to access the resulting directory server using the Apache Directory Studio.  Interestingly with embedded-sample example the module containing the [shared-ldap-schema](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/documentation/samples/trunk/embedded-sample/pom.xml) files is excluded from the classpath (my guess is that this is because the example is minimal implementation and not a fully standards compliant LDAP server).

Comment: The source is also available here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/directory/apacheds/tags/2.0.0-M3/

Comment: Thanks, I will give the embedded server example a good look, and see if it is useful.

Comment: Looks like 2.0-documentation is still horribly lacking and now they've gone and removed the documentation and examples for 1.5.7 you've referenced here.  I don't understand, is ADS dying?

Comment: Good point! Is ADS dying? There is no working example of embedding ApacheDS 2.0 :(